# K-9 Mail's REFRESH_OBSERVER?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Does anyone know how K9 Mail's REFRESH_OBSERVER should work? I tried the following as test, but I'm not getting a broadcast when I read/unread/delete/receive:

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".Monitor">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.fsck.k9.intent.action.REFRESH_OBSERVER"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
...
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="com.fsck.k9.permission.READ_MESSAGES" />
```

I also tried scheme=email with REFRESH_OBSERVER, but it didn't work.

Monitor.java:

```
public class Monitor extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("test", "onReceive()");
  }
}
```

On the other hand, the following works:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.fsck.k9.intent.action.EMAIL_RECEIVED" />
<action android:name="com.fsck.k9.intent.action.EMAIL_DELETED" />
<data android:scheme="email" />
</intent-filter>
```

But I would really like to get a broadcast when messages are read (for counting unread messages) and these two are insufficient for that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

REFRESH_OBSERVER is used only in src/com/fsck/k9/K9.java as part of the MessagingListener method searchStats(), to "let observers know a fetch occurred". It's only called when using the local search feature. Feel free to submit a patch to us if you wish to add some functionality to K-9. See https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/wiki